# Customize headline

Tags: beamer

I´d like to put a thin headline (using a empty theme) and write upper that headline the section or title the talk.

I mean, it would seem like a line down the title/section, in the up of the slides.

It is that possible? :)

I use this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[left,height=0pt,width=0.12\paperwidth]{sidebar}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[vertical shading][top=black,bottom=white]
```

I think that I need another `\useoutertheme` to add a horizontal line upper all the slides such that appear over that horizontal line the section/title.

I want something like this, in all slides, and controlling the wide of the lines and also putting the section upper the lines. Thanks! [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please specify your question (best with MWE). About which class are you talking etc (your tag suggesty `beamer`).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[left,height=20pt,width=0.12\paperwidth]{sidebar}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}[vertical shading][top=black,bottom=white] 

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamercolor{logo}{bg=black}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}% 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\beamer@sidebarwidth\relax}
            \vskip-\beamer@headheight
            \vskip2pt
            \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

            \vskip2pt
            \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\quad \insertsectionhead

            \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
        \end{minipage}
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{bla}

\begin{frame}
    content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Always those unappreciated answers... (+1)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you! Also for removing this question from the list of unanswered!